# Rails same render partial as html string ?

Tags: ruby-on-rails

So I come across with a problem where I would like to save a partial as an html string and render another partial with that string but I keep getting a double render error

```
def fruits 
  fruits = Fruits.all 
  market_html = "#{render partial: 'market', locals: {fruits: fruits}}"  
  render partial: 'super_market', locals {market_html: market_html}
end
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Do you want `render_to_string`?

```
market_html = render_to_string partial: 'market', locals: {fruits: fruits}
```